# Why is my jar not loading?

Tags: jar, coldfusion, loading

I am using the Jsoup jar file in my Coldfusion application. I was originally storing it in a local lib folder, but for security purposes we decided to store it in the cfroot lib folder. I uploaded the jar to the /lib folder in root, and added this code to Application.cfc:

```
this.javaSettings = {
    loadPaths: [
    "./lib/"
    ],
    loadColdFusionClassPath: true
};
```

However, my code (that was working before) now generates the following error:

```
ERROR
Object Instantiation Exception.
Class not found: org.jsoup.JsoupObject Instantiation Exception.
...
```

It seems the code is not finding/loading the jar file. How can I point the code towards the Jsoup jar file stored in root?

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion are you running?

Comment: Did you restart the application after you added that code?

Comment: Once you place the jar in \ColdFusion10\cfusion\lib, then there is no need to give reference for the same. Upon restarting ColdFusion service, the jar will be automatically loaded.

Comment: @DanBracuk - I tried restarting, still getting the error.

Comment: @AnitKumar - I removed the code to load the lib folder as it was causing a different error. I still get the error I posted even after restarting the application

Comment: (Edit) @froadie - Side comment about using `{cfroot}/lib`. That directory is already in the CF class path. So storing the jar there defeats the purpose of using CF10's dynamic class loader ;-) *RE: I removed the code to load the lib folder* 1) Did you remove the physical jars you added to `{cfroot}/lib`? 2) What is your current code for `javaSettings`? 3) Exactly how did you "restart" the application? 4) With java errors, the actual "cause" may be different than what is displayed in the error message header, so it is a good practice include the stack trace as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try backslash instead of forward-slash,

```
this.javaSettings = {
    loadPaths: [
    ".\lib\"
    ],
    loadColdFusionClassPath: true
};
```